# How do I determine color resolution of an output in DXGI/D3D?

Tags: c++, directx, resolution, win32

i'm was revising some code i wrote some time ago when working on the window wrapper for my rendering framework. The framework is based off DirectX, but it wasn't really using any D3D-related facility. Instead it was wrapping the EnumDisplaySettings call :

```
DEVMODE dm;
dm.dmSize = sizeof(dm);
int_32 count{ 0 };
while (EnumDisplaySettings(NULL, count, &dm))
{
    if (dm.dmPelsWidth == _width && dm.dmPelsHeight == _height)
    {
        m_width = dm.dmPelsWidth;
        m_height = dm.dmPelsHeight;
        m_color_resolution = dm.dmBitsPerPel;
        m_display_frequency = dm.dmDisplayFrequency;
        return true;
    }
    ++count;
}
```

Simple as that, this doesn't take into account the format. It does take the refresh rate in count (`DisplayFrequency`) that I've supposed being the same thing. I'm using this Win32 call because later whenever someone needs to set the window to fullscreen I apply the `DEVMODE` through `ChangeDisplaySettings()`.

I could have used the `IDXGIAdapter::EnumOutputs` call, but this doesn't give me the bits per pixel (or color resolution). I've done some tests and its value is 32 most of the times but I don't want to take it for granted. My question(s) is(are):

- Is there any way to get the color resolution through Direct3D ? is it strictly related to the format ?
- Is my approach correct at all ? because i'm having some doubts, should i keep using the Win32 calls or use the D3D ones ?

I apologize if this question has already been answered or if it has an obvious answer that I can't get, I bet I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to get the color resolution through Direct3D ? is it
>   strictly related to the format?

The color resolution (bits per pixel) of a surface is strictly bound to the [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173059%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of that surface, yes. You can use [CheckFormatSupport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to determine what formats are available for what uses at runtime.

> Is my approach correct at all ? because I'm having some doubts, should
>   I keep using the Win32 calls or use the D3D ones?

Due to the nature of the Windows platform and the way it's evolved over the years *and* focused on retaining backwards compatibility, there are a lot of ways to do things. Each will have various pros and cons but often any option will work fine. You may be able to accomplish what you want in slightly fewer lines with [DXGI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or slightly more (without knowing in detail what you are doing, it's hard to say). The DXGI approach is "more modern," if that matters to you.

However, if your code is functional and (appears) bug-free, I wouldn't *rush* to change it.